# Routing a React component to a rails partial?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ruby-on-rails-4.2, partials

I have a React component in my Rails 4.2 app that's being set up as `NewContactForm` through `contact/new`, and works nicely this way on its own. However, I've been looking to inject it into an existing Rails page ( `listings/new` or `listings/edit`, both rendered through a `_form` partial) for that this information is affiliated with, for better flow. As it stands, my routing requires that I have an exact path to render a component to; it there any way for me to render my component within a partial? I know the idea is to be able to inject React wherever with an app, I'm simply unsure how routing is handled in this situation (unless `views/contacts/new` is converted to a partial and passed in?).

app.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import WarehouseReport from './reports/warehouse'
import NewContactForm from './contacts/new-contact-form'

export default function App() {
  return <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/:account_id/warehouses/:warehouse_id/warehouse_report' component={ WarehouseReport }/>
    <Route exact path='/:account_id/contacts/new' component={ NewContactForm }/>
  </Switch>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing the router inside your component with the rails router here.

Routing that is specified here will handle routes inside the component itself. This means that clicking on anything inside the component will render something else in the component itself, but will not impact the route provided by your rails server.

The hypothetical scenario in which component would require its own routes is that you have a component which is a multi-step form, and you are using router to handle which step you are on.

To render the component inside the partial itself, it seems like the easiest way to do it is to use the combination of **react-rails** and react helpers

1. Add react-rails gem to your setup
   `gem 'react-rails'`
2. Bundle all React components so they become available for usage.
3. Use *react_component* helper to render the component inside your partial:

   `<%= react_component('ComponentName', {prerender: true}) %>`

Comment: Right now I'm generating React in my Rails app through `webpacker`. Will adding the new gem impact my existing components?

Comment: I haven't used that approach personnaly, but I do undesrstand what webpacker does. Does it create a new js file with the component for you inside the *packs* folder with the filename of the component file when you build ?

Comment: No, it just creates static module bundler of React into the asset pipeline. https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/how-to-add-react-js-to-your-ruby-on-rails-app-with-webpacker

Comment: But based on the article you linked, after building it does create an app jsx package inside `javascript/packs`  or  `javascript/components` folder. You can call that with the webpacker helper then: `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'component_name' %>` for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm only just getting comfortable with using them together, and less so with the terminology. So I could bypass the <Switch/> router in react using this method?

Comment: Yes. You can make 2 separate components in React, without the router. Then just use the webpacker helper to call each one where you need it.